# jQuery - restrict the amount of checkboxes checked

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a bunch of checkboxes, that I'd really like to make the user only able to select upto 5. Once selected 5, then the others are then disabled.

The HTML markup is:

```
<ul class="options-list">
 <li>
   <input type="checkbox" value="259" name="bundle_option[9][]" id="bundle-option-9-259" class="change-container-classname checkbox bundle-option-9">
   <span class="label"><label for="bundle-option-9-259">1 x Test 1</label></span>
</li>
 <li>
   <input type="checkbox" value="260" name="bundle_option[9][]" id="bundle-option-9-260" class="change-container-classname checkbox bundle-option-9">
   <span class="label"><label for="bundle-option-9-260">1 x Test 1</label></span>
</li>
 <li>
   <input type="checkbox" value="261" name="bundle_option[9][]" id="bundle-option-9-261" class="change-container-classname checkbox bundle-option-9">
   <span class="label"><label for="bundle-option-9-261">1 x Test 1</label></span>
</li>
 <li>
   <input type="checkbox" value="262" name="bundle_option[9][]" id="bundle-option-9-262" class="change-container-classname checkbox bundle-option-9">
   <span class="label"><label for="bundle-option-9-262">1 x Test 1</label></span>
</li>
 <li>
   <input type="checkbox" value="263" name="bundle_option[9][]" id="bundle-option-9-263" class="change-container-classname checkbox bundle-option-9">
   <span class="label"><label for="bundle-option-9-263">1 x Test 1</label></span>
</li>
 <li>
   <input type="checkbox" value="264" name="bundle_option[9][]" id="bundle-option-9-264" class="change-container-classname checkbox bundle-option-9">
   <span class="label"><label for="bundle-option-9-264">1 x Test 1</label></span>
</li>
</ul>
```

My main problem is targeting the checkboxes.

Can I target them using the `name` value of `bundle_option[9][]`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, but because you have `[` and `]`'s in the name (which have a special meaning in jQuery selectors), you have to escape them with `\\`; ([taken from API docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/));

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \.

```
$(':checkbox[name="bundle_option\\[9\\]\\[\\]"]');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/G9JCw/

Comment: Ah, I knew it was something like that. I'd just forgot that I needed to escape each bracket. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the checked selector to grab the selected checkboxes, like,

```
$("input[name='bundle_option[9][]']:checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    var count = $(".checkbox:checked").length;
    if (count >= 5) {
        $(".checkbox").not(":checked").prop("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else{
        $(".checkbox").removeProp("disabled");
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/2YMwS/)